# Determining optimal maintenance windows for end-user system patching

Tags: sccm, maintenance

What would be good information to use in order to identify and report on times when the highest number of transient end-user systems such as laptops are connected to the network?

Available to me is event log information from the following systems: Domain Controllers and end-user systems.

I would like to make a data-informed decision on what maintenance window we should use for our patch management process.

Comment: Are you patching workstations or the servers that workstations are accessing?

Comment: workstations...

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct answer to your question but if you set the update available time to a differential before the install deadline, you can worry less about this. This will enable the laptops to download the updates when they are connected to the network but not install them. The updates will be ready to go once the deadline is reached as long as they check in before the deadline.